# Bluetooth to android inputstream and displaying the values

Tags: android, multithreading, bluetooth, byte, inputstream

I am trying to develop an application that reads an input stream of bytes from a bluetooth modeule. I then want to display the bytes on the screen each time a new one is sent. This is what I have done:

```
// Define the Start Button function
mStartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(View v) {
        read();
        updateDisplay();
    }
});
```

Then the read function: (note: I have used  inStream = btSocket.getInputStream() earlier to get the stream. a is a global int variable)

```
public void read() {
 if (inStream != null) {
      try {
         a = inStream.read(); // Reads a single byte from this stream and returns it as an integer in the range from 0 to 255.
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }
}
```

Then the updateDisplay function:

```
private void updateDisplay() {
    mValueDisplay.setText(
            new StringBuilder()
            .append(a).toString()
            );
}
```

Now, I only call the read function everytime I want to get a value from the stream. I want this to happen continuously. Also note that the inStream.read() returns an integer. I want this integer to be displayed.

Should I implement thread to do this continuously in the background? And how will the thread send the value to the screen?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that my HTC Wildfire was the problem. The Bluetooth chat from the android development site did not work on it, and that is why I tried to make another way around connecting to a bluetooth device. Finally, when my colleague tried his Samsung Galaxy SII, it worked perfectly. My HTC wildfire, set me back 2 weeks!!! Thanks htc!